# Could not open connection to host (ubuntu server) on port 23, 5432, 3306

Tags: networking, mysql, connection, postgresql, telnet

I have recently installed few packages for telnet, mysql and postgreSQL. I can access all these service locally on the ubuntu server but somehow I am not able to access these services from other machines. 
Below are the active internet connections using:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn 

tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:23     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      18776/inetd
tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:3306   0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      19451/mysqld
tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:5432   0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      8453/postgres
```

I am not able to figure out what I am missing. I am almost sure that I have configured these packages correctly to allow outside world connections.

When I am trying telnet from windows, I got "Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed"

I doubt, my router might have blocked these connections but I don't know how to troubleshoot or unblock these connections. Please suggest, Many thanks!

Comment: are you trying to access it from the local network or the internet ??

Comment: I am trying to access it from internet

Comment: Does your machine have a public IP or a local network IP ?? 
i.e, 192.168.x.x , 10.x.x.x , ...

Comment: My machine has local network IP address i,e 192.168.0.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your machine has a local IP address, if you want to access it from the internet you have to  do a **Static Port Mapping** or **Static Nating**.

the best way to do that is from your router if it support static/custom port mapping by do the following

**forward 192.168.0.33 port 23** to **23**

and then you can access your server from your public IP address.

these are sample images for the router configurations.

[image]
[image]

also you can know your public IP from google https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=my+ip or from your router.

Answer (score 0):

Can try

> nmap ip_address_of server

from cilent

also check firewall on server

> sudo ufw status

Comment: `22                         DENY        Anywhere`  
`2222                       ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`80                         ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`25                         ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`143                        ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`110                        ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`993                        ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`995                        ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere`  
`23                         ALLOW       Anywhere`

Comment: above is the result of `sudo ufw status`. Sorry for bad formatting but I don't understand how this damn thing works. I tried using two spaces at the end of each line also using linebreaks <br/>

Comment: ok, port 23 is for telnet. Is open. If I understand you try to connect to server and server and pc on same lan? If not, and traffic flow is pc -> router -> internet -> router -> server, you must add port forwarding rule to router on server side.

Comment: @2707974 has a point. If you are using a xDSL modem/router, then look in the setup for something like "virtual servers" or "port forwarding" and create a rule for each one of your servers. Also for postgres make sure that the sever is configured to listen for external TCP/IP connections. The default is to listen only to `localhost` for security reasons. Read [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks 2707974 and hmayag. Suggestion to add port forwarding rule in router, works :)